# DLNA sequential playback, how it work?

Tags: upnp, dlna

If the tracks are played sequentially, who initiates the switch to the next track?

1. Control Point. It asks the Digital Media Renderer for elapsed time from the beginning of the track and the next track starts.

or

2. Digital Media Renderer? How?

Comment: The OpenHome Media is a extention of upnp that support audio playlist.   http://www.openhome.org/wiki/OhMedia

Comment: UPnP supports playlists just fine, there's no need for extensions (especially ones that claim to be open standards but seem to be completely controlled by a single company)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As always with DLNA, the answer is "it depends".

- The control point can handle this on it's own, keeping track of the playlist and setting the next URI when playback state goes to paused.
- The control point could use `SetNextAVTransportURI()` when a song starts playing: this way the renderer can pre-buffer the next song and can provide slightly more features (as an example cross fade or skipping to next song).
- The control point could use `SetStaticPlaylist()` or `SetStreamingPlaylist()` to provide the renderer with the whole playlist

`SetNextAVTransportURI()` and `Set*Playlist()` are optional AVTransport features so the control point cannot trust on them to be available.